# Cast varchar that holds some strings to integer field in informix

Tags: sql, casting, informix

I have 2 rows from 2 tables in a database that I want to compare.

Column1 is on table1 and is an Integer field with entries like the following

`column1
 147518
 187146 
 169592`

Column2 is on table2 and is a Varchar(15) field with various entries but for this example lets use these 3:

`column2
 169592
 00010000089
 DummyId`

For my query part of it relies on checking if rows from table1 are linked to the rows in table2, but to do this, I need to compare column1 and column2.

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN (SELECT column2 FROM table2)`

The result of this using the data above should be 1 row - 169592

Obviously this wont work (A character to numeric conversion process failed) as they cannot be compared as is, but how do I get them to work?

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN (SELECT CAST(column2 AS INTEGER) FROM table2)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN (SELECT (column2::INTEGER) column2 FROM table2)
```

Using Server Studio 9.1 if that helps.

Comment: I think it would help us if you showed us sample data in tabular form.

Comment: How do you get three integer values stored in one row of a column of type integer?  On the face of it, you're storing about 27 characters in a varchar(15) field too. What do you know about the variability of the first part of column2?  Is the number always 6 digits?  Which version of Informix could help too.

Comment: Have you considered casting the integers into strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `ISNUMERIC` in following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(column2) = 1 THEN CAST(column2 AS INT) END FROM table2)
```

Comment: So this got me started, but unfortunately informix does not have the ISNUMERIC function, so I found the following creation of the function that worked with your script.

`create function isnumeric(inputstr varchar(15)) returning integer;
define numeric_var decimal(15,0);
define function_rtn integer;

on exception in (-1213)
let function_rtn = 0;
end exception with resume

let function_rtn = 1;
let numeric_var = inputstr;

return function_rtn;
end function;`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try casting the int to a string:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE cast(column1 as varchar(15)) IN (SELECT column2 FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose there is no need to create a special function that you'll not find on other environments.

Let's create a test case for your example:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
        col1 INT,
        col2 INT
);

CREATE TABLE tab2 (
        col1 VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(147518,1);
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(187146,2);
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(169592,3);

INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES(169592);
INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES('00010000089');
INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES('DummyId');
```

The first query you run was like:

```
SELECT  t1.*
FROM    tab1 AS t1
WHERE   t1.col1 IN (SELECT t2.col1 FROM tab2 AS t2);
```

This will raise an error because it tries to compare an `INT` with a `VARCHAR`

> [infx1210@tardis ~]$ finderr 1213
>     -1213   A character to numeric conversion process failed.
>
> A character value is being converted to numeric form for storage in a
>     numeric column or variable. However, the character string cannot be
>     interpreted as a number. It contains some characters other than white
>     space, digits, a sign, a decimal, or the letter e; or the parts are in
>     the wrong order, so the number cannot be deciphered.
>
> If you are using NLS, the decimal character or thousands separator
>     might be wrong for your locale.
>
> [infx1210@tardis ~]$

Then you've tried to cast a `VARCHAR` into a `INT` which resulted in the same error, you should tried the other way:

```
> SELECT  t1.*
> FROM    tab1 AS t1
> WHERE   t1.col1::CHAR(11) IN (SELECT t2.col1 FROM tab2 AS t2);
>

       col1        col2

     169592           3

1 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

Check also if you don't get faster results using the [EXISTS](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1394.htm?lang=en):

```
>   SELECT        t1.*
>   FROM    tab1 AS t1
>   WHERE   EXISTS (
>                       SELECT  1
>                       FROM    tab2 AS t2
>                       WHERE   t1.col1::CHAR(11) = t2.col1
>   );

       col1        col2

     169592           3

1 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

Another way possible is to just join the tables:

```
> SELECT    t1.*
> FROM      tab1 AS t1
>               INNER JOIN tab2 AS t2
>                   ON (t1.col1 = t2.col1);

       col1        col2

     169592           3

1 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of this question was answered by @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas where he said to use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(column2) = 1 THEN CAST(column2 AS INT) END FROM table2)
```

But informix does not have a built in function for ISNUMERIC, so the following created it:

```
create function isnumeric2(inputstr varchar(15)) returning integer;
define numeric_var decimal(15,0);
define function_rtn integer;

on exception in (-1213)
let function_rtn = 0;
end exception with resume

let function_rtn = 1;
let numeric_var = inputstr;

return function_rtn;
end function;
```

And then the first query above worked for me.